# How to Code PHP for Twilio to forward SMS to Email

Tags: php, twilio, sms, forwarding

Coding newby here.

I am trying to write some PHP code to enable SMS forwarding to email with a Twilio phone number.
Unfortunately, I haven't had any success in doing so.

I saw some tutorials using SendGrid, but I would rather use my own PHP code on my web server.

Can anyone point me to a good source or if possible, provide step by step instructions?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There is a ["forward SMS to email" quick deploy here](https://www.twilio.com/code-exchange/forward-sms-email) where you don't need a server--Twilio will host it for you!

[This is how you could do it with PHP](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181788-Forwarding-SMS-Messages-to-your-Email-Inbox):

```php
<?php 
/** 
* This section ensures that Twilio gets a response. 
*/ 
header('Content-type: text/xml');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
echo '<Response></Response>'; //Place the desired response (if any) here

/** 
* This section actually sends the email. 
*/ 

/* Your email address */
$to = "your-email@example.com";
$subject = "Message from {$_REQUEST['From']} at {$_REQUEST['To']}"; 
$message = "You have received a message from {$_REQUEST['From']}. Body: {$_REQUEST['Body']}"; 
$headers = "From: webmaster@example.com"; // Who should it come from?

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

To make that code above work,

1. Modify the code below to update the `From` and `To` email addresses.
2. Publish that file to a Twilio-accessible URL on your web server.
3. Update your Twilio Phone Number's webhook with your application's URL.

If you're a Node.js person, here is a [tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/07/forward-incoming-sms-messages-to-email-with-node-js-sendgrid-and-twilio-functions.html) that uses [Twilio Functions](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/functions), Twilio's serverless environment for hosting web (Node) apps.

Let me know if this helps at all!